# Flex PopUpManager Modality Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

I have a spark window container which has a list of files that are downloadable, on clicking a file the file is getting downloaded using the URLStream method and using the ProgressEvent method to track the % of file downloaded as :

```
stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
```

Now in the progressHandler method, I am calling the preogressBar in a titleWindow using popUpManager as :

```
public function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {           
                tWin.title = "Please Wait";
                tWin.width=400;
                tWin.height=100;
                pb.width=300;
                pb.height=30;
                pb.labelPlacement="center";
                pb.label = "Downloading " + Math.round(event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100).toString() + "%";
                pb.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);
                tWin.addChild(pb);
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(tWin, this, true);
                PopUpManager.bringToFront(tWin);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(tWin);
            }
```

Here tWin and pb are titleWindow and ProgressBar respectively which I have defined globally above.

Also at the completin=on of the event, I am calling another function to remove the popUpManager as :

```
public function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(tWin);
                             }
```

Now when I execute the code,the progressBar pop's up and shows the progress and makes the original window modal as I have turned the modality to **TRUE** in addPopUp function and after the download finishes, the popup is removed but the modality of the window remains as it is i.e. the window is not clickable.

Also if I turn the modality to **FALSE** in addPopUp function then the progressbar doesnot show up above the window, instead it is somewhere behind the original window and cannot be seen.(I only see a part of it)

Can anybody help with how can I resolve this error of displaying back the original window once the pop-up is removed.

Comment: ...progress event happens a lot of times. Why do you execute all adding/sizing code many times instead of adding popup once and then only change progressbar progress?

Comment: @user1875642
Hi just one more question, that when I download the file, the progressbar correctly displays the % of file loaded, but when I select another file for download, although the file is downloaded but the % of file downloaded is not shown in the progressbar and it remains at 100% all the times while the file is downloaded. Could you please suggest what could be the cause of the progressbar showing the correct % of file download only for the first file that is downloaded and not for other files ?

Comment: are you sure that you don't create new progressbar? anyways, debugging is the best way to solve such problems.

Comment: I am sure that I am not creating a new progressbar.. I also debugged the problem,, in the debugger it correctly shows the % of file downloaded but it does not show the same on the progressbar.
Have also tried the various methods after searching on the net and on this site,, but it has not worked,, any help..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress event should not be adding the pop up

```
    stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
    stream.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, initProgress);




    public function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {     
            pb.width=300;
            pb.height=30;
            pb.labelPlacement="center";
            pb.label = "Downloading " + Math.round(event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100).toString() + "%";
            pb.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);  
        }

    public function initProgress(event:Event):void
        {
            tWin.title = "Please Wait";
            tWin.width=400;
            tWin.height=100;
            tWin.addChild(pb);
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(tWin, this, true);
            PopUpManager.bringToFront(tWin);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(tWin);
        }
```

Comment: Hi just one more question, that when I download the file, the progressbar correctly displays the % of file loaded, but when I select another file for download, although the file is downloaded but the % of file downloaded is not shown in the progressbar and it remains at 100% all the times while the file is downloaded. Could you please suggest what could be the cause of the progressbar showing the correct % of file download only for the first file that is downloaded and not for other files ?